# Rendering loop problem in ReactJS UseEffect Method

Tags: reactjs

Hi I am new developer at ReactJs. I have a problem about useEffect rendering. I have an example and i am trying to change background image with time but useEffect make rendering so much and my background image is staying in a loop with time. I just want to change my images with order like bg1 bg2 bg3 etc. 
How can I solve this infinite render?

my example .tsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { connect } from "../../../store/store";

const LeftPart = (props: any) => {

     const [value, setValue] = useState(1);
     const {loginLeftImagesLength} = props;
     const changeLeftBackgroungImage : any = () =>{
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            if (value <= loginLeftImagesLength.payload) {
                setValue(value+1);
            } else{
                setValue(1);
            }
        }, 3000);
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
     };

     useEffect(() => {
        changeLeftBackgroungImage();
    });

    return (

        <div className="col-xl-7 col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm col-12">
            <img id="image" src={"../../../assets/images/bg"+value+".jpg"} style={{ width: "100%", height: "99vh" }} alt="Login Images"></img>
        </div >
    )
}

export default connect((store: any) => ({ loginLeftImagesLength: store.loginLeftImagesLength }))(LeftPart) as any;
```

Comment: What is the issue ? infinite render?

Comment: Yes infinite render continuously.

Comment: why did you choose to use useEffect? have you tried looking at just using map? https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html. If you really need to use useEffect, remember you can add an array of variables as second input which will restrict rendering only on changes of those variables

Comment: when I update to length, it should change automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have infinite render as you have not specified any dependencies in your `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
        changeLeftBackgroungImage();
},[]); // Will run this hook on component mount.
```

Also you could do it in this way

```
useEffect(()=>{
  const timer = setTimeout(()=>{
    if (value <= loginLeftImagesLength.payload) {
                setValue(value+1);
            } else{
                setValue(1);
            }
  },3000)
  return ()=>{ // Return this function from hook which is called before the hook runs next time
    clearTimeout(timer)
  }
},[,value]) // RUN THIS HOOK ON componendDidMount and whenever `value` changes
```

Comment: It works correctly.  Settimeout solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: We just need to edit  as "ClearTimout()" instead of "ClearTimer()".

Answer (score 0):

Why not put this entire code inside the useEffect hook.

```
useEffect(() => ) {

const {loginLeftImagesLength} = props;
     const changeLeftBackgroungImage : any = () =>{
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            if (value <= loginLeftImagesLength.payload) {
                setValue(value+1);
            } else{
                setValue(1);
            }
        }, 3000);
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
     };[changeBGStateHere])
```

use if else statements to change the background...

if (value === 1) {

changeLeftBackgroungImage();

} else (value === 2) {

and so on.

```
Let the interval change the state and let useEffect rerender when the state for the time changes.
```